# Xcode 3.2.4 and Mac OS X 10.5

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-leopard, backwards-compatibility, xcode3.2

I have a simple question: does Xcode 3.2.4 work on Mac OS X Leopard (10.5) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Xcode 3.2 was released with Mac OS X v10.6 "Snow Leopard", and won't install on any earlier version of Mac OS X.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#3.x_series)

To get earlier version of Xcode, go to [Apple Connect](http://connect.apple.com/), click “Downloads” link, then go to “Developer Tools” in the right sidebar and search for “3.1.4″.

Comment: that's pity. where can i download erlier verions of xCode?

Comment: @user441393: I've extended my answer for 3.1.4 that should run on Leopard.

Comment: maybe somebody tell me, where to download erliel iphone sdk's? need for 3.1.2

Comment: @VladLazarenko: no, it's the other way around in Xcode 3.1 ... Xcode is bundled into the iPhone SDKs!